# What is the naming convention for Sn and Pb in inter-metallic compounds?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, terminology, materials, metallurgy

How would one go about naming inter-metallic (specifically, transition post-transition) compounds containing tin and lead?

It is usually easy figuring out the naming of such compounds as they follow a simple naming convention, for example ruthenium german**ide**, niobium aluminium**ide** and so on.

But what about tin? Would you get ruthenium *stannide*? *Stannumide*? Or something completely different? Same goes for lead, but I feel like I've heard the name aurous plumbide referring to $\ce{AuPb2}$ before.

Comment: @Mithoron Though Sb isn't unreasonable to include? 'Stibnide'?

Comment: @ChristianS.O. -- AFAIK neither Sn nor Pb is a transition metal, so I removed that tag.

Comment: Worked in metallurgy ( R&D Dept) my whole career and this problem never came up. Generally called intermetalllics and maybe a likely composition.

Comment: @hBy2Py Sb would be antimonide, example [Nickel Antimonide](https://www.americanelements.com/nickel-antimonide-12035-52-8)

Answer (score 4):

After doing some digging I've found evidence to support that tin based inter-metallic compounds should be named 'stannide' such as in the paper by Fickenscher et al. [[1](https://doi.org/10.1515/znb-2015-0050)].

#### Reference

1. Fickenscher, T.; Rodewald, U. C.; Niehaus, O.; Gerke, B.; Haverkamp, S.; Eckert, H.; Pöttgen, R. The Stannides $\ce{RE3Au6Sn5}$ $(\ce{RE} = \ce{La}, \ce{Ce}, \ce{Pr}, \ce{Nd}, \ce{Sm})$ – Synthesis, Structure, Magnetic Properties and $\ce{^{119}Sn}$ Mössbauer Spectroscopy. *Zeitschrift für Naturforschung B* **2015**, 70 (6), 425–434. DOI: [10.1515/znb-2015-0050](https://doi.org/10.1515/znb-2015-0050).